# Writting to file until I want to stop

Tags: python, list, file

I have 3 inputs:

```
name = input(">> ")
price = input(">> ")
count = input(">> ")
print("\nDo you want to add more products?")
more = input(">> ")
```

First of all, I write these three parameters into a file (empty or filled with something nevermind).  After the program asks me "Do you want to add more?", if I  do not type anything and press enter, then the program will write my answers into a file with this format.

```
name/price/count
```

If I press any key and hit enter then the program will continue asking me for 3 more inputs.  If I stop after this then the file look will look like this:

```
name/price/count/name/price/count
```

And I can continue this sequence as many times as needed.

*So far, this is what I have and it it working.*

```
readingWriting("someFile.txt", dataOfInputs)
print("\nSuccessfully!\n")
```

**Question:** How can I make this program work as described?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful

Comment: Ah...maybe a while loop?

Comment: @polka: What's wrong? I think OP's question is clear.

Comment: I took a lot of liberties with the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```
def readingWritting(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('/'.join(data))

dataOfInputs = []
more = 'yes'

while more != '':
    name = input(">> ")
    price = input(">> ")
    count = input(">> ")

    dataOfInputs.append(name)
    dataOfInputs.append(price)
    dataOfInputs.append(count)

    print("\nDo you want to add more products?")
    more = input(">> ")


readingWritting("someFile.txt", dataOfInputs)
print("\nSuccesifully!\n")
```

Demo:

```
kevin@Arch ~> python test.py 
>> Kevin
>> 2
>> 23

Do you want to add more products?
>> yes
>> Bob
>> 33
>> 12

Do you want to add more products?
>> 

Succesifully!

kevin@Arch ~> cat someFile.txt 
Kevin/2/23/Bob/33/12
```